# How to do 301 permanent redirect a single URL with parameters

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting, seo, nginx

In nginx 1.0, how do I redirect a single URL with parameters, e.g.
from **/page?id=3** to **/my-new-url**  with a 301 permanent redirect?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
location /page { if ($arg_id = 3) { rewrite ^ /my-new-url? permanent; } }
```